# Javascript regexp that matches '.' not preceded by '\' (lookbehind alternative)

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

I am making a (Excel like) number formater function in javascript. I want to use templates like "0 000.00" and "000.000.000" which would produce:

```
format(123456789,"0 000.00") >> "123 456 789.00"
format(123456789,"000\.000\.000") >> "123.456.789"
```

So I need to match '.' not preceded by '\'. Since there is no lookbehind in javascript, what would be the regexp for splitting the whole and decimal part of a template?

This unfortunately doesn't work :-(

```
template.split(/(?<!\\)\./);
```

Comment: I don't think that JavaScript regular expressions support the look-behind feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the string and use a negative lookahead instead.

```
template.split("").reverse().join("")
        .split(/\.(?!\\)/)
        .split("").reverse().join("");
```

That's a "fun" way of doing it but for your case there are other ways that may be better. Like replacing all `\.` with a magic string like `__MAGIC__`, splitting by `.`, then undoing the magic strings.

Comment: I first learned this technique from a man whose name I can't spell, otherwise I'd give him credit: Tim P.