# Javascript regexp that matches '|' not preceded by '\' (lookbehind alternative)

Tags: javascript, regex, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to split string `name\|dial_num|032\|0095\\|\\0099|\9925` by delimiter `|` but it will skip `\|`.
I have found solution in this link: [Javascript regexp that matches '.' not preceded by '\' (lookbehind alternative)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320767/javascript-regexp-that-matches-not-preceded-by-lookbehind-alternative) but it skips `\\|` too.

The right result must be: `[name\|dial_num,032\|0095\\,\\0099,\9925]`.

The rule is in case `\\\|` or `\\\\\|` or etc, `|` is still a valid delimiter but in case `\\\\|` or even more, it isn't.

Any help will be appreciate .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the usual workaround is to use `match` instead of `split`:

```
> s = "name\\|dial_num|032\\|0095\\\\|\\\\0099|\\9925"
"name\|dial_num|032\|0095\\|\\0099|\9925"
> s.match(/(\\.|[^|])+/g)
["name\|dial_num", "032\|0095\\", "\\0099", "\9925"]
```

As a side note, even if JS did support lookbehinds, it won't be a solution, because `(?<!\\)|` would also incorrectly skip `\\|`.

Answer (score 0):

I challenged myself to use replace String method..

I got the right result using [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/#javascript) (a popular online tester for PCRE, Javascript and Python regular expressions engines)

```
// input : name\|dial_num|032\|0095\\|\\0099|\9925
// regex : ([^\\|](?:\\\\)*)\|                       with global flag
// replacement : $1,
// output: name\|dial_num,032\|0095\\,\\0099,\9925   <= seams okey right !?
```

Test ..

```
var str = 'name\\|dial_num|032\\|0095\\\\|\\\\0099|\\9925';
str = str.replace(/([^\\|](?:\\\\)*)\|/g,'$1,');
console.log(str);
// > name\|dial_num,032\|0095\\,\\0099,\9925
```